# jQuery VLOOKUP() script

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

The script below demonstrates `VLOOKUP` by showing which languages appear from column 1 in column 2.

Is there a way that I can refine my code to pass in an exact match? Also, I notice in my `console.log`, that it is iterating the for loop many times on each word that it finds.  Can that be consolidated or condensed to be more lightweight?

Disclaimer: I am not an expert in the Excel VLOOKUP function.  I do know how to use it and I do understand its purpose.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("tr").each(function() {
    $(this).find('td:eq(0)').addClass("colOne");
  });
  $("tr").each(function() {
    $(this).find('td:eq(1)').addClass("colTwo");
  });

  var tdPeriod = $("td");

  tdPeriod.each(function() {
    var tdText = $(this).text().toString();
    var replaceTD = tdText.replace(/\./g, "").toString();
    $(this).text(replaceTD)
  });

  $('td.colOne').each(function(x) {
    for (i = 0, z = $('.colTwo').length; i < z; i++) {
      var c2Text = $("td.colOne:eq('" + x + "')").text().toString();
      var rowArr = c2Text.split(" ").splice(0, 1);
      $("td.colTwo:contains('" + rowArr[i] + "')").css("color", "#FFF").addClass(rowArr[i]);
      if ($("." + rowArr[i] + "").length > 0) {
        console.log(rowArr[i]);
      }
    }
  });

  $('tr:eq(0) td').addClass("rowOne").css("background-color", "#000");

  $('.colTwo').each(function() {
    var coldText = $(this).text().toString();
    var colTD = coldText;
    $(this).text(colTD)
  });
});
```

```css
.colOne {
  background-color: #ACE;
}
.colTwo {
  background-color: #FAF;
}
td {
  border: solid 1px #000;
}
.rowOne {
  background-color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=497 style='border-collapse:
 collapse;width:373pt'>
  <!--StartFragment-->
  <col width=329 style='mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-alt:12032;width:247pt'>
    <col width=168 style='mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-alt:6144;width:126pt'>
      <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
        <td height=20 class=xl64 width=329 style='height:15.0pt;width:247pt'>mddStandards</td>
        <td class=xl64 width=168 style='border-left:none;width:126pt'>S172004701</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
        <td height=20 class=xl63 style='height:15.0pt;border-top:none'>Danish (Denmark)
        </td>
        <td class=xl63 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Bangali</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
        <td height=20 class=xl63 style='height:15.0pt;border-top:none'>German (Germany)
        </td>
        <td class=xl63 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Chinese (Simplified)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
        <td height=20 class=xl63 style='height:15.0pt;border-top:none'>Greek (Greece)</td>
        <td class=xl63 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Chinese (Traditional)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
        <td height=20 class=xl63 style='height:15.0pt;border-top:none'>English (United States)</td>
        <td class=xl63 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Czech</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
        <td height=20 class=xl63 style='height:15.0pt;border-top:none'>Spanish (Spain. Traditional Sort)</td>
        <td class=xl63 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Dutch</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
        <td height=20 class=xl63 style='height:15.0pt;border-top:none'>Finnish (Finland)
        </td>
        <td class=xl63 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>English</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
        <td height=20 class=xl63 style='height:15.0pt;border-top:none'>French (France)
        </td>
        <td class=xl63 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Egyptian</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
        <td height=20 class=xl63 style='height:15.0pt;border-top:none'>Kahan (Italy)</td>
        <td class=xl63 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>French</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
        <td height=20 class=xl63 style='height:15.0pt;border-top:none'>Japanese (Japan)
        </td>
        <td class=xl63 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>German</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
        <td height=20 class=xl63 style='height:15.0pt;border-top:none'>Korean (Korea)</td>
        <td class=xl63 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Hindi</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
        <td height=20 class=xl63 style='height:15.0pt;border-top:none'>Dutch (Netherlands)
        </td>
        <td class=xl63 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Indonesian</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
        <td height=20 class=xl63 style='height:15.0pt;border-top:none'>Norwegian. Bokmal (Norway)</td>
        <td class=xl63 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Italian</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
        <td height=20 class=xl63 style='height:15.0pt;border-top:none'>Polish (Poland)
        </td>
        <td class=xl63 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Japanese</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
        <td height=20 class=xl63 style='height:15.0pt;border-top:none'>Portuguese (Brazil)
        </td>
        <td class=xl63 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Kannada</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
        <td height=20 class=xl63 style='height:15.0pt;border-top:none'>Romanian (Romania)
        </td>
        <td class=xl63 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Korean</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
        <td height=20 class=xl63 style='height:15.0pt;border-top:none'>Russian (Russia)
        </td>
        <td class=xl63 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Malay</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
        <td height=20 class=xl63 style='height:15.0pt;border-top:none'>Swedish (Sweden)
        </td>
        <td class=xl63 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Norwegian</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
        <td height=20 class=xl63 style='height:15.0pt;border-top:none'>Thai (Thailand)
        </td>
        <td class=xl63 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Pakistani</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
        <td height=20 class=xl63 style='height:15.0pt;border-top:none'>Turkish (Turkey)
        </td>
        <td class=xl63 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Polish</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
        <td height=20 class=xl63 style='height:15.0pt;border-top:none'>Afrikaans (South Africa)</td>
        <td class=xl63 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Portuguese - Brazil</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
        <td height=20 class=xl63 style='height:15.0pt;border-top:none'>Hindi (India)</td>
        <td class=xl63 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Portuguese - Portugal</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
        <td height=20 class=xl63 style='height:15.0pt;border-top:none'>Malay (Malaysia)
        </td>
        <td class=xl63 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Romanian</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
        <td height=20 class=xl63 style='height:15.0pt;border-top:none'>Chinese (Simplified. PRC)</td>
        <td class=xl63 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Sinhalese</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
        <td height=20 class=xl63 style='height:15.0pt;border-top:none'>German (Switzerland)
        </td>
        <td class=xl63 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Spanish</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
        <td height=20 class=xl63 style='height:15.0pt;border-top:none'>English (United IGngdom)</td>
        <td class=xl63 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Turkish</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
        <td height=20 class=xl63 style='height:15.0pt;border-top:none'>Italian (Switzerland)
        </td>
        <td class=xl63 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Thai</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
        <td height=20 class=xl63 style='height:15.0pt;border-top:none'>Portuguese (Portugal)
        </td>
        <td class=xl63 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Vietnamese</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
        <td height=20 class=xl63 style='height:15.0pt;border-top:none'>Chinese (Traditional. Hong Kong English (Australia)</td>
        <td class=xl63 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>Dutch (w Flemish review)
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
        <td height=20 class=xl63 style='height:15.0pt;border-top:none'>Spanish (Spain. International Sort)</td>
        <td class=xl63 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
        <td height=20 class=xl63 style='height:15.0pt;border-top:none'>French (Switzerland)
        </td>
        <td class=xl63 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
        <td height=20 class=xl63 style='height:15.0pt;border-top:none'>English (New Zealand)
        </td>
        <td class=xl63 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
        <td height=20 class=xl63 style='height:15.0pt;border-top:none'>Arabic (U.A.E.)
        </td>
        <td class=xl63 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <!--EndFragment-->
</table>
```